# aggregation in mongodb with push and group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to make an aggregation of two collections but I do not get it, I also want to group everything with a push.

This is my sensor collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId ("5b3e3ce0f0ed5174a3097cde"),
    "name": "co2_int",
    "type": "climate",
    "place": "interior",
    "user": ObjectId ("5b10176084195a07f63c942a"),
    "greenhouse": ObjectId ("5b1027896933440c030f8a6b"),
    "__v": 0
}
```

Datagreenhouses collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId ("5b3e40d6f0ed5174a3097f4e"),
    "name": "co2_ext",
    "timestamp": ISODate ("2018-08-30T16: 25: 13.159Z"),
    "value": "200",
    "greenhouse": ObjectId ("5b1027896933440c030f8a6b"),
    "sensor": ObjectId ("5b1027dc6933440c030f8a6e"),
    "__v": 0
}
```

and this is my aggregation:

```
Datagreenhouse.aggregate ([

    {"$ match": {
    "name": {$ in: arr}}},
    {
      "$ lookup": {
          "from": "sensor",
          "localField": "_id",
          "foreignField": "_id.sensor",
          "as": "sensor_type"
      }
    },


    {"$ group": {
        "_id": {
            "timestamp": "$ timestamp",
            "name": "$ name",
            "value": "$ value",
            "sensor_type": "$ sensor_type"
        },
        "Count": {"$ sum": 1}
    }},

    // {$ unwind: '$ type'},
    {"$ group": {
        "_id": "$ _id.timestamp",
        "measurements": {
            "$ push": {
                "name": "$ _id.name",
                "count": "$ Count",
                "value": "$ _id.value",
                "sensor_type": "$ _id"
            },
        },
        "count": {"$ sum": "$ Count"}
    }},
    {"$ sort": {"_id": -1}},
    {"$ limit": 1}
    ]
```

I need to recover the place of the sensor collection that is associated with that data.

answer:

```
{
            "_id": "2018-08-30T16: 25: 13.159Z",
            "measurements": [
                {
                    "name": "temperature_int",
                    "count": 1,
                    "value": "33",
                    "sensor_type": {
                        "timestamp": "2018-08-30T16: 25: 13.159Z",
                        "name": "temperature_int",
                        "value": "33",
                        "sensor_type": []
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "co2_int",
                    "count": 1,
                    "value": "70",
                    "sensor_type": {
                        "timestamp": "2018-08-30T16: 25: 13.159Z",
                        "name": "co2_int",
                        "value": "70",
                        "sensor_type": []
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "temperatura_ext",
                    "count": 1,
                    "value": "90",
                    "sensor_type": {
                        "timestamp": "2018-08-30T16: 25: 13.159Z",
                        "name": "temperatura_ext",
                        "value": "90",
                        "sensor_type": []
                    }
                }
            ],
            "count": 3
        }
```

I do not know how to solve this problem.

Greetings and thank you.

*****EDIT*****

I edit the post does not work correctly it always shows the same value the place

```
{
    "DatagreenhouseRecuperado": [
        {
            "_id": "2018-08-30T16:25:13.159Z",
            "medidas": [
                {
                    "name": "co2_ext",
                    "count": 1,
                    "value": "200",
                    "place": "interior"
                },
                {
                    "name": "co2_int",
                    "count": 1,
                    "value": "70",
                    "place": "interior"
                },
                {
                    "name": "temperatura_ext",
                    "count": 1,
                    "value": "90",
                    "place": "interior"
                },
                {
                    "name": "temperatura_int",
                    "count": 1,
                    "value": "45",
                    "place": "interior"
                }
            ],
            "count": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

where the name is _ext it would have to put exterior and not interior that the value of the field place in the collection sensors.

Aggregarion:

```
Datagreenhouse.aggregate([

    {"$match": {
    "name" : { $in: arr }} },
    {
      "$lookup": {
          "from": "sensors",
          "localField": "sensor",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "sensor"
      }
    },
    {"$unwind":"$sensor"},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "timestamp": "$timestamp",
            "name": "$name",
            "value": "$value",
            "sensor_type": "$sensor.type"

        },
        //"sensor":{"$first":"$sensor"},
        "place":{"$first":"$sensor.place"},
        "Count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},

    //{$unwind:'$type'},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.timestamp",
        "medidas": {
            "$push": {
                "name": "$_id.name",
                "count": "$Count",
                "value": "$_id.value",
                //"sensor_type":"$ _id.sensor_type",
                //"sensor":"$sensor"
                "sensor_type":"$ _id.sensor_type",
                "place":"$place"
            },
        },
        "count": { "$sum": "$Count" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 1 }
    ]
```

Collections:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1027e46933440c030f8a6e"),
    "name" : "temperatura_ext",
    "type" : "clima",
    "place" : "exterior",
    "usuario" : ObjectId("5b10176084195a07f63c942a"),
    "invernadero" : ObjectId("5b1027896933440c030f8a6b"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

***EDIT02*****

My final goal is the following:

```
{
            "_id": "2018-08-30T16: 25: 13.159Z",
            "measurements": [
                {
                    "name": "temperature_int",
                    "count": 1,
                    "value": "45",
                    "place": "interior"
                },
                {
                    "name": "co2_ext",
                    "count": 1,
                    "value": "200",
                    "place": "exterior"
                },
                {
                    "name": "temperatura_ext",
                    "count": 1,
                    "value": "90",
                    "place": "exterior"
                },
                {
                    "name": "co2_int",
                    "count": 1,
                    "value": "70",
                    "place": "interior"
                }
            ],
            "count": 4
        }
```

The place field must be the real one that refers to the collection of sensors, I just need to enter the value of that field. Now he is always giving me back the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your lookup by switching local and foreign field.

`$unwind` to reduce the sensor data from array to document and add the sensor to the `$push`.

```
Datagreenhouse.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"name":{"$in":arr}}},
  {"$lookup":{"from":"sensor","localField":"sensor","foreignField":"_id","as":"sensor"}},
  {"$unwind":"$sensor"},
  {"$ group":{
    "_id":{
      "timestamp":"$timestamp",
      "name":"$name",
      "value":"$value",
      "sensor_type":"$sensor.type",
      "place":"$sensor.place"
    },
    "Count":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$ group":{
    "_id":"$_id.timestamp",
    "measurements":{
      "$ push":{
        "name":"$_id.name",
        "count":"$Count",
        "value":"$_id.value",
        "sensor_type":"$ _id.sensor_type",
        "place":"$_id.place"
      }},
      "count":{"$sum":"$Count"}
  }},
  {"$sort":{"_id":-1}},
  {"$limit":1}
])
```

Updated:

```
Datagreenhouse.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"name":{"$in":arr}}},
  {"$lookup":{
     "from":"sensor",
      "localField":"_id",
      "foreignField":"greenhouse",
      "as":"sensor"
  }},
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sensor": {
        "$map": {
          "input":"$sensor",
          "as": "sen",
          "in": {
            "place":"$$sen.place"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "timestamp":"$timestamp",
      "name":"$name",
      "value":"$value"
    },
    "sensor":{$first:"$sensor"},
    "Count":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {$"unwind":"$sensor"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.timestamp",
      "measurements":{
      "$ push":{
        "name":"$_id.name",
        "count":"$sensor",
        "value":"$_id.value",
        "place":"$_id.place"
      }},     
     "count":{"$sum":"$Count"}
  }},
  {"$sort":{"_id":-1}},
  {"$limit":1}
])
```

Comment: I need to recover the place field of the sensor that I have to add to what you have commented?

Comment: Updated answer to include the place field from sensor collection.

Comment: I edit the post does not work correctly it always shows the same value the place

Comment: Updated aggregation. please review.

Comment: Hello,
continues to return the same value in all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what your requirement is .Can you review your group stage ? I can take a look if you can edit the post to include few more documents that I can use to get the result that you see ?

Comment: hello I have edited the by with the name edit02, I do not know if that is enough.

Comment: Let me try to explain how I understood your question.  Greenhouse  collection has many to one relation with sensor collection. Lookup returns sensor row related to each green  house row.  Group operation to count the no of occurrences on name, timestamp, sensor type and sensor place followed by second group on timestamp to get all the  measurements and count the no of occurrences by timestamp. Can you try to run one stage at a time and examine the output ? This will give you idea after which a there the result is not expected and we can work from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174572/discussion-between-manolait-and-veeram).

Comment: I'm still not sure what is the problem here. It appears to be working for me. I have added an update to the answer based on your documents. Please review.

Comment: hello, I do not understand why we have changed the foreignField to greenhouse when the information is available in the sensor collection.

Comment: foreign field is the field in the sensor collection which is greenhouse and local field is the field in the greenhouse collection which is _id based on the documents that you posted in chat.

Comment: I will try to raise the solution in another way, since this does not work for me.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yw. Sorry I couldn't help you. Please consider creating a new post with all the details and someone can help you.